# I created function witch work inside of button, but when i try to made it global for app it stop working

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, qt, pyside6

I tried changing formula of the function but i run off from ideas.
This is code for my "banking" app. The function is used to sort amount of money to banknotes.

I'm using python 3.10

Pyside6 and app is built by QT designer.

I tried to use class but it also failed.

If you have any idea what I did wrong, I would love to hear how I can repair it.

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Marbi\Desktop\Project\test2.py", line 139, in sub
> self.bankomat()
> File "C:\Users\Marbi\Desktop\Project\test2.py", line 32, in bankomat
> self.bankomat.dw = 0
> AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'dw'

Code:

````
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loader = QUiLoader() #ładowanie kodu strony do pythona
        self.window = loader.load("bank.ui", self)
        self.window.setFixedSize(500, 400)
        self.show()  # wykonywanie
        #łaczenie sygnałów
        self.window.sub_butt.clicked.connect(self.sub)
        self.window.log_butt.clicked.connect(self.nxt)
        self.window.log_1.clicked.connect(self.log)
    def nxt(self):
        self.window.pages.setCurrentIndex(self.window.pages.currentIndex() + 1)
    def log(self):
        x_c=self.window.credit_card.text()
        y_c=self.window.pin.text()
        x="0000"
        y="0000"
        if x_c==x and y_c==y:
            self.window.pages.setCurrentIndex(self.window.pages.currentIndex() + 1)
        else:
            self.window.feedback_1.setText("Your access has been blocked for 1 hour")
            self.window.pages.setCurrentIndex(0)
            self.window.credit_card.setText("")
            self.window.pin.setText("")
    def bankomat(self):
        w = self.window.withdraw.text()
        w = int(w)
        self.bankomat.dw = 0
        self.bankomat.sto = 0
        self.bankomat.p = 0
        self.bankomat.d2 = 0
        self.bankomat.dz = 0
        if w % 10 == 0:
            resztadw = w % 200
            w = w / 200
            dw = int(w)
            self.bankomat.dw = dw
            if resztadw == 0:
                dw = int(w)
                self.bankomat.dw = dw
            else:
                sto = resztadw / 100
                if sto > 0:
                    sto = int(sto)
                    self.bankomat.sto = sto
                    resztasto = resztadw % 100
                    p = resztasto / 50
                    if p > 0:
                        p = int(p)
                        self.bankomat.p = p
                        resztap = resztasto % 50
                        d2 = resztap / 20
                        if d2 > 0:
                            d2 = int(d2)
                            self.bankomat.d2 = d2
                            resztad2 = resztap % 20
                            dz = resztad2 / 10
                            if dz > 0:
                                dz = int(dz)
                                self.bankomat.dz = dz
                    else:
                        resztap = resztasto % 50
                        d2 = resztap / 20
                        if d2 > 0:
                            d2 = int(d2)
                            resztad2 = resztap % 20
                            dz = resztad2 / 10
                            if dz > 0:
                                dz = int(dz)
                                self.bankomat.d2 = d2
                        else:
                            resztad2 = resztap % 20
                            dz = resztad2 / 10
                            if dz > 0:
                                dz = int(dz)
                                self.bankomat.dz = dz
                else:
                    resztasto = resztadw % 100
                    p = resztasto / 50
                    p = int(p)
                    if p > 0:
                        p = int(p)
                        self.bankomat.p = p
                        resztap = resztasto % 50
                        d2 = resztap / 20
                        if d2 > 0:
                            d2 = int(d2)
                            self.bankomat.d2 = d2
                            resztad2 = resztap % 20
                            dz = resztad2 / 10
                            if dz > 0:
                                dz = int(dz)
                                self.bankomat.dz = dz
                    else:
                        resztap = resztasto % 50
                        d2 = resztap / 20
                        if d2 > 0:
                            d2 = int(d2)
                            self.bankomat.d2 = d2
                            resztad2 = resztap % 20
                            dz = resztad2 / 10
                            if dz > 0:
                                dz = int(dz)
                                self.bankomat.dz = dz
                        else:
                            resztad2 = resztap % 20
                            dz = resztad2 / 10
                            if dz > 0:
                                dz = int(dz)
                                self.bankomat.dz = dz
            self.window.inf2.setText(inf2_txt)
            self.window.inf.setText("")
        else:
            self.window.inf.setText("Podaj liczbę, która jest wielokrotnością liczby 10")
            self.window.inf2.setText("")
    def druk(self):
        b_200_txt = str(bankomat.dw)
        self.window.b_200.setText(b_200_txt)
        b_100_txt = str(bankomat.sto)
        self.window.b_100.setText(b_100_txt)
        b_50_txt = str(bankomat.p)
        self.window.b_50.setText(b_50_txt)
        b_20_txt = str(bankomat.d2)
        self.window.b_20.setText(b_20_txt)
        b_10_txt = str(bankomat.dz)
        self.window.b_10.setText(b_10_txt)
    def sub(self):
        bal=5000 #balance
        w=self.window.withdraw.text() #withdraw
        inf2_txt=str(w)
        w=int(w)
        if w<=500:
            if w<bal:
                if w < (bal / 2):
                    self.bankomat()
                else:
                    self.window.inf.setText("You've reached your limit")
                self.druk()
        elif w>bal:
            self.window.feedback_1.setText("Your access has been blocked for 24 hours")
            self.window.pages.setCurrentIndex(0)
        else:
            self.window.inf.setText("Żądana kwota jest za duża do zrealizowania przez ATM")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=MainWindow()
    win.setWindowTitle("Project")
    sys.exit(app.exec())```
````

Answer (score 0):

In function definition of bankomat,

```
def bankomat(self):
    w = self.window.withdraw.text()
    w = int(w)
    self.bankomat.dw = 0 <------
```

bankomat is not a model but a function and it does not contain any attribute named dw which you are trying to access using self keyword.

Comment: So how i should declare this?

Comment: can you tell me what you are trying to do with this bankomat function? and that "dw" is it just a local variable or is it an attribute of a class?